# Use vlookup to get exact match while is_sorted is TRUE

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to use Google Sheets **VLOOKUP** to get an **exact match** while using the **sorted==TRUE** option ?

- Prefer to use VLOOKUP because I'm return multiple columns.
- Would like to use the sort option because the data range is very large
  (20,000 rows)

I didn't find any option in while reading the docs. Asking in case, there is an option I may have missed.

EDIT; I also checked the **MATCH** function, but the sort option is identical to VLOOKUP - so same situation.

EDIT; an ArrayFormula [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cjLrds-TpDV0T-Qt9mvdU3uSkxf9bDDufPzfIZ12v70/edit) for users to reference

EDIT; full formula for my purposes for reference using **Answer** (double VLOOKUP) - very fast for even 20,000 rows

```
 ARRAYFORMULA(IF(VLOOKUP(B:B,SORT(UNIQUE(B:B)),1,TRUE)=B:B,VLOOKUP(B:B,QUERY(A:B,"select B, count(A) group by B order by B label count(A) ''"),2,TRUE),0))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The double vlookup approach is to search for the primary key itself first, and only if it's found, proceed to retrieving the values from other columns.

If A:B is already sorted by A, and the value we look for is 42, then the formula is:

```
=if(vlookup(42, A:B, 1, true) = 42, vlookup(42, A:B, 2, true), na())
```

where the first vlookup checks if 42 is in column A, and only then passes the job to the second.

If A:B is not sorted, it can be sorted on the fly as in

```
=if(vlookup(42, sort(A:B), 1, true) = 42, vlookup(42, sort(A:B), 2, true), na())
```

Comment: Just a side note, that on the fly sort wouldn't make sense as it can only increase the computing cost.